# Function to build JSON-RPC

Tags: javascript

Is there a function to build JSON-RPC in Javascript without libraries but not actually send it? I want to send it over Websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a JSON object, then use `JSON.stringify` to turn it into a string if that's what you're looking for.

For example, to build the [wikipedia v1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Version_1.1_.28Working_Draft.29) example:

```
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "method": "confirmFruitPurchase",
    "id": "194521489",
    "params": [
        ["apple", "orange", "Mangoos"],
        1.123
    ]
}
```

You could do this:

```
var rpc = {
    version: 1.1,
    method: "confirmFruitPurchase",
    id: 194521489,
}
```

etc.

You can modify this like you would a normal javascript object using `.` or `[]` notation then `var JSON_RPC_string = JSON.stringify(rpc)` when you are ready to send it.

I don't think you need a library to create these, but you could create your own simple helper functions if there is something you keep repeating.

Comment: Cannot upvote due to insufficient reputation and could not accept as answer that soon, thanks man.